# JSF <include> doesn't work in template

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2, include

I'm a newbie in Java and JSF and trying to create a test page using JSF template, `<ui:include>` and `<ui:insert>`. As a result I get only `<ui:insert>` blocks on the page, but `<ui:include>` is not rendered. Could someone advise what's wrong here? Here's my template `main_template.xhtml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html lang="en"
      xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html">
    <h:head>
        <title>Title Here</title>
    </h:head>
    <h:body>
        <div id="header">
            <ui:include src="header.xhtml"/>
        </div>
        <div>
            <div id="menu">
                <ui:insert name="menu">Menu string</ui:insert>
            </div>
            <div id="content" >
                <ui:insert name="content">Main Content</ui:insert>
            </div>
        </div>
    </h:body>
</html>
```

Here's `index.xhtml`:

```
<ui:composition template="WEB-INF/templates/main_template.xhtml"
     xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
     xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets"
     xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html">

    <ui:define name="menu">
        <h1>Menu will be here</h1>
    </ui:define>

    <ui:define name="content">
        <h1>New content here</h1>
        <p>Blah blah</p>
    </ui:define>
</ui:composition>
```

..and `header.xhtml`:

```
<ui:composition 
      xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html">
    <h2>Header page</h2>
    <p>Include page blah blah lorem ipsum</p>
</ui:composition>
```

Comment: If header.xhtml and main_template.xhtml are stored in different folders, then you need setup proper path of header.xhtml in `ui:include`. If it in same folder try use `<ui:include src="/WEB-INF/templates/header.xhtml" />`.

Answer (score 0):

You missed `/` before `WEB-INF` when defining the template file.

```
<ui:composition 
                template="/WEB-INF/templates/main_template.xhtml"
                xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
                xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets"
                xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html">
</ui:composition>
```

Comment: I tried both with and without `/` and the result is the same

Comment: Nope I didn't. `<ui:include>` html is simply not present on the page.

Comment: What's your `jsf` version?

Comment: @mav3r1ck If `<ui:include>` not works, did you get `Menu string` text what you defined in `template file`?

Comment: `Menu String` is within `insert` and it works fine and displays what is in `define`. JSF 2.2

Comment: @Ranhith It started working suddenly when I used following URL - `http://localhost:8080/app1/faces/index.xhtml`. Is something wrong with my project definition that it doesn't work with app context `/app1'?